# Cookie only undefined at top level domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, cookies

I'm using the cookie.js Jquery plugin to manage my cookies. It runs in an Symfony2 environment dev mode. I only the the strange thing that my cookies are undefined only at the top level.

This way I'm setting my cookie:

```
$.cookie("username", "name", { expires : 365 });
```

White the following alert I'm viewing it.

```
alert($.cookie("username"));
```

On every page except the home page (main domain url) it is showing the correct result. Only on www.website.nl/app_dev.php I'm getting back "undefined" ?

Comment: Did you try adding the path `$.cookie("username", "name", { path: '/', expires : 365 });`

Comment: which jquery cookie plugin? I see one discontinued plugin, and another that has not been actively developed since 2014

Comment: By default, if you set a cookie on `www.example.com`, it will not be accessible on `example.com`. By default, if you set a cookie from `example.com/path`, it will not be accessible from `example.com/`. Which do you mean?

Comment: Adding "path: '/', " fixed the problem!